# Accesing the data from a row where trigger is assigned

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have encountered a problem when I've designed this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER StudentNewAssignment BEFORE INSERT
ON classassignment FOR EACH ROW 
insert into StudentTeacherLog(studentID, teacherID, description, reason)
values((select ID from student where classID = classassignment.classID), 1, 'Test', 'da');
```

Basically. When trigger hits, I want to access the data from newly inserted row in classassignment and use it in a subquery which will extract data from student table related to the 'data accesed from table where trigger hits'.
Hope I've made it clear. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html says:

> Within the trigger body, you can refer to columns in the subject table (the table associated with the trigger) by using the aliases `OLD` and `NEW`.
>
> `OLD.col_name` refers to a column of an existing row before it is updated or deleted. `NEW.col_name` refers to the column of a new row to be inserted or an existing row after it is updated.